# Is there a limitation for the PHP addition (+) function?

Tags: php

I think i run in kind of a limitation in PHP.

Does anyone has a solution for this problem?

```
$num1=pow(2,500);
#Works. Output:
3273390607896141870013189696827599152216642046043064789483291368096133796404674554883270092325904157150886684127560071009217256545885393053328527589376

$num2=pow(2,565);
#Works. Output:
36893488147419103232

$num3=$num1+$num2;
# No error, but the output is incorrect. It is simply the value of "num1".
3273390607896141870013189696827599152216642046043064789483291368096133796404674554883270092325904157150886684127560071009217256545885393053328527589376
```

Its think its not a problem with the float. Because I can do this:

````
$zahl3=$zahl1*2;
#Output:
6546781215792283740026379393655198304433284092086129578966582736192267592809349109766540184651808314301773368255120142018434513091770786106657055178752

# But I cannot do something like this: 
$zahl3=$zahl1+10; ``` 

Maybe a problem with the vars and the space?
````

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is related to the MAX value of float

From https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

> The size of a float is platform-dependent, although a maximum of approximately 1.8e308 with a precision of roughly 14 decimal digits is a common value (the 64 bit IEEE format).

Comment: Its think its not. I can do this: $zahl3=$zahl1*2;
Maybe a problem with the vars and the space?

Comment: But I cannot do something like this: $zahl3=$zahl1+10;

Comment: I agree with @nixUser: it is not only the maximum value but mostly the finite precision (appr. 14 digits) that is the limiting factor here.